# passing values to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to pass value "0000002" in string format to next activity like below:

```
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtras("EmpID", "0000002");
```

In second activity

```
Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras();
System.out.println("Test " + info.getString("EmpID")); // this line printing "null" value instead of "0000002".
```

I am able to pass and fetch the other strings successfully. I am not able to fetch the EmpID.

Please help me.

Comment: where do you have this `Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras()` in `SecondActivity`

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? Where you send the other strings that does work?

Comment: use putExtra for istead of putextras

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Sample

From 1st Activity

```
Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
localBundle.putString("Loan Amount", editText1.getText().toString());
localBundle.putString("Loan Tenture", editText2.getText().toString());
localBundle.putString("Interest Rate", editText3.getText().toString());
Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
localIntent.putExtras(localBundle);
startActivity(localIntent);
```

and in Activity2

```
String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Loan Amount");
String string2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Loan Tenture");
String string3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Interest Rate");
```

For your case, you can use like

```
Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
localBundle.putString("EmpID", "0000002");
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtras(localBundle);
startActivity(pass);
```

and in SecondActivity you can get the EmpId like

```
String empId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EmpID");
```

----------------- ***Another Way*** -----------------

```
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtra("EmpID", "0000002");
startActivity(pass);
```

In second activity you can get the EmpId like

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String empId = bundle.getString("EmpID");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `pass.putExtra("EmpID", "0000002");` not putExtras

Comment: Yes, it has putExtra method.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtra("EmpID", "0000002");
startActivity(pass);
```

In second activity

```
Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras();
System.out.println("Test " + info.getString("EmpID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Activity A
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtra("EmpID", "0000002");

//Activity B
Intent intent = getIntent();
String EmpID = intent.getStringExtra("EmpID");
System.out.println("Test " + EmpID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this:
When passing value:

```
Intent pass = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
pass.putExtra("EmpID", "0000002");
```

To get the value:

```
System.out.println("Test " + getIntent().getStringExtra("EmpID"));
```

Comment: whats new in this answer?